# Alter language select on a node add/edit form

Tags: 8, forms, i18n-l10n

Wonder if anyone has had any experience altering the options presented to a user from the language select on a node add/edit form. I have some custom access control ont the site and basically I'm looking to remove options based on a individual editors access to approved locales. If they haven't been approved to make edits for a certain locale then they shouldn't see an option to add a translation for that locale in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://cgit.drupalcode.org/redirect/tree/src/Form/RedirectForm.php#n70

The language widget/form element is designed so that when you explicitly provide some options, then it doesn't add the default.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and pointing in the right direction. I was able to achieve the desired functionality I was looking for.

Comment: While I see this code, it doesn't seem to apply to the node form. At least not anymore. Instead of "language" it now has "langcode" in the node form array. When you drill down to `$form['langcode']['widget'][0]['value']` there is no "#options" index. As I look further I do not see any other place where it should have those options. So I am left scratching my head.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in an #after_build function, the #options aren't build until after form_alters get called.

```
<?php

/**
* Impliments hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
**/
function hook_form_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#after_build'][] = '_hook_node_form_after_build';
}

/**
 * Afterbuild to alter language options for node edit forms.
 */
function _hook_node_form_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
  if(isset($form['langcode']['widget'][0]['value']['#options'])){
    // alter options here
  }
  return $form;
}
```